# iTextPDF HTML2PDF(Java) Page and table width

Tags: html, css, itext, width

I am trying to generate a pdf from a html which has tables. The html file itself is generated from Freemarker

The sample html/css is here https://codepen.io/codasif/pen/WNzVYjB
[image]
The css is simple - without any flexbox contents. The page width is fixed at 1200px with max-width: 1200px;
And the blue divs are floated with float:left. However the output pdf seems distorted with the blue divs not appearing as in html and also the table truncated. The table headers are missing too.
[image]
Any pointers of what I am doing wrong.

Java code is straightforward:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream ms = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(ms));
PageSize pagesize = new PageSize(1200,960);

String BASEURI = "base-path-of-html-and-css-folder";
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
converterProperties.setBaseUri(BASEURI);

FileInputStream fileIo = new FileInputStream("outputhtml.html");
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("b.pdf");
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(fileIo,writer,converterProperties);
writer.close();
```

I updated the width and the table now fits page width, but the divs are still overflowing and the table headers are missing.
[image]

Comment: Note that the css for the blue divs use "inline-block" and width with percent values. We use 50% width to put the nth and n+1th box on a new line where n=1,3,5....https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/pdfhtml-support-for-inline-block-with-a-width-percent-value

Comment: I set the page size.. and the table fits, but the blue divs are still overflowing. See updates on the original question.

Comment: The table header issue has been resolved. We were using background-color on thead element. The background-color needs to be applied to the 'thead th' element instead. The inline-block with width percentage issue still remains for the blue-divs. Maybe related to this https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/pdfhtml-support-for-inline-block-with-a-width-percent-value